# How to make MIUI-like tabs

Tags: java, android, tabs, styling, android-tabs

I want to make MIUI style tabs for my application.

I tried using a selector but I ended up having just colored tabs.
I also tried creating a png to be the background but once again, it didn't change the tab size.

I want to make tabs like these:
[image: Tabs]

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use the great [ViewPagerExtentions](https://github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions) library, which allows to create simillar tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use buttons instead of tabs. User background image for the buttons. Will it be very difficult to handle if u user buttons?

Comment: Yes. It will. There is a purpose for the TabWidget. With buttons you can't get the same experience as a tabs.
By the way, I see you are new. So first welcome! second, you didn't give a complete answer, so I think it is more suitable for as a comment...